# How to cross-reference in GoClipse?

Tags: eclipse, go, cross-reference, goclipse

I have installed Eclipse (Mars) with Goclipse plugin on my Macbook yesterday. They initially work perfectly. But today I found I cannot do cross reference (that means cmd+click on a keyword cannot jump the definition). And the console shows:

> ```
> Running: oracle -pos=/Users/myname/coreos/naas/server/src/mycompany.com/hh/naas-server/main.go:#389,#389
> -format=json describe mycompany.com/hh/naas-server
> FAILED: Could not start process:    
> Reason: Cannot run program "oracle": error=2, No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: Probably (I do not use Goclipse) you'll have to install the Oracle tool: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Voker suggested, GoClipse is just an Eclipse plugin. For it to compile, build, run your Go packages and applications, it requires the Go tools.

You can set the standard Go tool on the settings page:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Go
```

You can set some non-standard, differnet Go tools on the page:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Go -> Tools
```

This is where you can tell GoClipse where your oracle and gocode programs are located.

You have to download oracle yourself, but the settings page above provides you a button:

<kbd>Download Go oracle (run: `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle`)</kbd>

So you have to `go get` it either manually or by the above-mentioned button. Install it using `go install`, so you will have the executable binary `oracle`. You have to set the full path of `oracle` on the `Go -> Tools` settings page, and it will work.

While we're at it: I also recommend you to install gocode (https://github.com/nsf/gocode) which will provide you the auto-complete feature (<kbd>CTRL+SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>CMD+SPACE</kbd> for a list of exported identifiers in package, list of methods etc.). Just also use the button on the same settings page:

<kbd>Download gocode (run: `go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode`)</kbd>

Install it and set the full path of the resulted executable binary `gocode`.